# Select object by several enum values in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, enums, rails-activerecord

I use enum to store statuses of my model:

```
enum status: [ :fresh, :approved, :rejected, :returned, :completed, :removed ]
```

Now I want to select object with several values of status, something like this:

```
Documents.find_by_status(:fresh, :returned)
```

How should I do it correctly in Rails 4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every enum attribute has integer representation of its value in table column.
By default your statuses will have values – fresh: 0, approved: 1, rejected: 2 and so on.
The simplest way to get instances with one or another value is to call something like that

```
Document.where(status: [0, 1])
```

To improve readability you can implement scope in you model.

```
class Document < ActiveRecord::Base
  enum status: %i(fresh approved rejected returned completed removed)

  scope :find_by_status, ->(*args) { where(status: self.statuses.values_at(*args)) }
end
```

And use it more humanized way

```
Document.find_by_status(:fresh, :returned)
```